# Django not rendering template after POST method

Tags: django, templates, post

I'm trying to render the Django template after uploading a file (POST method). The issue is: I insert some `print()` inside the `POST request.method` and everything is working fine (terminal VSCode) but the template (HTML) is not being displayed inside the `render()` function.

View.py:

```
def index(request):
if 'GET' == request.method:
    print("It didn't work it!")
    print(request.FILES['file'])
    return render(request, 'auditoria_app/index.html')
else:
    print('It worked it!')
    excel_file = request.FILES["file"]

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file, data_only=True)
    wb.security.workbook_password = 'Rnip*2020'

    inputsCombo = wb['Inputs COMBO']
    inputsDNCombo = wb['Inputs DN COMBO']
    outputCombo = wb['OutPut COMBO']
    faixas = wb['Faixas']

    wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('media/sigma.xlsx', data_only=True)
    sigma = wb2['sigma']
    sic = wb2['Performance']

    # wb4 = openpyxl.load_workbook('media/ultimoContrato.xlsm', data_only=True)
    # ultimoContrato = wb4['Base']

    numeroIbms = inputsCombo['F5'].value
    ibms = []

    output = outputResults(numeroIbms, outputCombo)

    for i in range(8, 8 + numeroIbms):
        ibm = Ibm(i, inputsCombo, inputsDNCombo, outputCombo, faixas, sigma)
        ibms.append(ibm)
        print(ibm.numeroIbm)
        # sigmaReport(sigma, ibm)

    return render(request, 'auditoria_app/index.html',
                  {'ibms': ibms,
                   'numeroIbms': numeroIbms,
                   'output': output,
                   })
```

Message displayed on VSCode terminal:

```
It worked it!
Outside: SAE_R360_pagnussat.xlsm
1038108
1049885
[04/Sep/2021 21:18:36] "POST /auditoria/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5132
```

Comment: can you please post your models and template file as well please

Comment: what do you see when you make a post call

Comment: @MohitC the page does not load and stays on the current template! I only see the message displayed on VSCode terminal...

Comment: Please post the template as well and the urls